# ASP.NET MVC - References a master/layout page from another project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

Is it possible to include/reference a master (layout) page from another project? I have a "common" project that houses the look and feel that can be reusable (and able to override/customize) across many projects, but not sure what would be the approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile your razor views .. look into

http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/

Then you can reference them into your project where you want to use it.